# RegistryKey.GetValue for WinLogon Fails to Return All Values

Tags: registry, registrykey

When using RegistryKey.GetValueNames to retrieve the values of "LOCALMACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", not all values of the key are returned. It only returns 10 values, which matches the ValuesCount of the key. However, if I manually count the values of the key using "regedit", I have 33 values recorded. There is no way to update the values count of key, either in "regedit" or code. It appears that this "bad" count is impacting using the GetValue method, which I am trying to use.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that since I had "Prefer 32bit" enabled for the project, it was accessing "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" and not "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon". Disabling the option enable the method to function properly. I just got a count of 32.

Thanks to [Viorel](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/viorel_/?ws=usercard-mini)!